# How to style react-intl-tel-input input field?

Tags: reactjs

I have been trying to style react-intl-tel-input input field but i am getting no where. Does anyone know how it can be styled?

Answer (score 1):

Looks at this document: https://patw0929.github.io/react-intl-tel-input/?selectedKind=Usage&selectedStory=Custom%20Style&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=0&addonPanel=storybooks%2Fstorybook-addon-knobs

there is a style props on the component and you can style it with it.

```
{
  "transform": "rotate(3deg)",
  "color": "red",
}
```